# Проверка данных без цикла

Tags: java

Мне нужно обработать несколько тысяч объектов.

```
public Region getRegion(Location location) {//location - еденица которая 
//должна совпадать с один из регионов
        Region region = null;
        for (Region rg : getRegions()) {
            if (rg.isContact(location)) {
                region = rg;
                break;
            }
        }
        return region;//222 задержка
    }
```

Проблема заключается в том, что обработка циклом `for` всех данных, как я понял, занимает очень большую часть времени.
Как можно реализовать проверку всех объектов без использования цикла?

Или же как можно свести задержку на нет.

Comment: Кажись рекурсия в данном контексте будет не разумна, если вы об этом. И вы проверьте. сколько уходит времени на цикл, проблема может быть и в другом, уж пару тыс, это не пару миллионов. И совет, не используйте в цикле `getRegions()` вынесите за цикл, в переменную.

Comment: Что означает фраза "проблема заключается в том что при обработке циклом for все данных"? Она выглядит незаконченной. И "очень большая часть времени" - это сколько? Наконец, что именно делает метод `getRegions`?

Comment: Метод getRegions() возвращает объекты классов с их содержимым (Они загружены все в память)

Проблема заключается в том что цикл занимает слишком большое количество времени.

Comment: Похоже, нужно использовать какой-либо алгоритм пространственной индексации. Их море, что подойдёт - зависит от особенностей ваших "регионов". Примитивный пример - всё пространство разделено на квадраты, и индексы квадрата - x/size, y/size